# Java example where letting "this" escape during construction results in inconsistent state of an object

Tags: java, concurrency, constructor, this

In the book **Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz**, there is a section about safe construction practices. The author covers how letting the "this" reference escape during construction can lead to an "incompletely constructed object".

> But an object is in a predictable, consistent state only after its constructor returns, so publishing an object from within its constructor can publish an incompletely constructed object. This is true *even if the publication is the last statement in the constructor*. If the this reference escapes during construction, the object is considered not properly constructed.<sup>8</sup>

> 8. More specifically, the this reference should not escape from the *thread* until after the constructor returns.

I'm looking for an example program that deliberately let's the this reference escape to another thread. The example should give an "unexpected" output because an incompletely constructed object is accessed. Importantly, the publication of this should be the last statement in the constructor!

**Can anyone provide an example program which prints an "unexpected" value in practice?**

I've tried this program:

```
public class ThisEscape {
    private int state;

    public ThisEscape() {
        state = 42;

        try {
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(state)); // this escapes here
            t.start();
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThisEscape();
    }
}
```

Here the this reference escapes to the anonymous class that implements Runnable (created using a lambda expression). The program prints 42 when I run it, but if my understanding is correct, it could theoretically print 0 or perhaps another value != 42.

Comment: You would have to run it a great many times concurrently to have a good chance of seeing the effect. Also, "Importantly, the publication of this should be the last statement in the constructor" is incorrect: this should *never* be published from within the constructor. Recall that within certain rules (basically as long as the end result is the same), Java may reorder execution of statements, so it the coded order of statements doesn't strictly need to be the execution order.

Comment: @Bohemian I know that it's generally bad to let this escape from the constructor. What I mean is that the example I'm looking for should not let this escape before the 'state' of the object is set. I want to see an example where we get an 'unexpected' output, even though the publication happens after the initialization of the state.

Comment: The idea is that the asynchronous call of publish inside the constructor (running on another thread) may try to access the object before the constructor actually returns. If you set the publish as last statement you will have to run your tests a lot of times and hope the JVM decides to park this thread in favour of the other thread. However, if you put a current thread breakpoint at the end of the constructor, the other thread will call this object before initialisation complete and you may observe the wrong behaviour mentioned

Comment: "Just run your tests a lot" is __really bad advice__. If you break a rule such that the JVM is free to do a thing or not do a thing (example: Read a field from thread A that was written by thread B without a happens-before relationship, thus giving the JVM the right for thread A to observe either the before _or_ the after state, at the whim of the JVM) is not like a coinflip. Your JVM will do the same thing every time. Until tomorrow when a different song is on your music player, or your laptop is running on battery instead of mains power. "run tests more" just gives false sense of sec.

Comment: Your example can only gives the result of 42 since the execution of a thread is synchronised after the call to `Thread::start`.

Answer (score 3):

> it could theoretically print 0 or perhaps another value != 42.

Incorrect. The [JMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) talks about observability and allows for the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) caching (or not) any variable. It also allows for shearing, which you will never be able to observe on any 64-bit JVM implementation I'm aware of; you'll need to download a 32-bit JVM to try to observe it. Shearing is seeing half of an update to a 64-bit variable. The only variable types in java that are defined as 64-bit are doubles and longs. Other types may also occupy 64 bit. However, it is not valid for a JVM to allow observation of shearing on anything but `long` and `double` values. However, **other than shearing, a JVM is not allowed to make up numbers**. In other words, in your example, you can observe 0, and you can observe 42. Nothing else can be observed (not even when these are `long`, due to 0 and 42 both having all zero bits for their upper 32 bit block). Or rather, if you manage to observe any other value, your JVM is broken: It breaks the JVM Specification.

### Shearing

As I said, it's mostly irrelevant, in that no current JVM impl will ever do it, but [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) still legally allows a JVM to shear `long` and `double` values. Not any other type of value (not even references, even though on 64-bit hardware those tend to be 64 bit too):

given:

```
class Haha {
  int x = 0;

  public String describe() {
    int c = x;
    return c == 0 ? "0" : c == -1 ? "-1" : ("HUH?? " + c);
  }

  void run() {
    boolean flip = false;
    while (true) {
      x = flip ? -1 : 0;
      flip = !flip;
    }
  }
}
```

And having 'run' continually flip `x` from 0 to -1, calling `describe` **CANNOT** return `HUH??`. If you have a JVM that does that, **it is broken**.

However, *make that `int` a `long`* and a JVM is legally allowed to print HUH?? here. Specifically, two more values are now allowed to be observed: -1 is 64 one-bits, and 0 is 64 zero-bits. The 2 extra observable values are the sheared variants: 32 zero-bits followed by 32 one-bits (which, in long terms, is 4294967295), or 32 one-bits followed by 32 zero-bits (which, in long bits, is -4294967296).

The reason should be obvious: `x = 0L;` where `x` is a long (a 64-bit value) on 32-bit hardware requires two write ops: One to write 32 zero bits to the 'top' and another to write 32 zero bits to the 'bottom', and the JVM gives itself the freedom to allow other code to see those bits halfway through that operation, *and* gives itself the freedom to order those writes (top first, or bottom first) either way - whatever is more efficient on the hardware your JVM runs on. That's the reason for all these 'the JMM may or may not do X' - it's to allow a JVM to pick whatever is the most efficient thing on a given architecture/OS combo.

### A snippet that shows the danger

... probably doesn't exist.

I explained the shearing situation to hopefully make clear what's happening here:

1. It is obvious why the JMM explains that shearing might occur - after all, avoiding it would make any attempts to read/write a `long` or `double` on 32-bit JVM implementations **incredibly** expensive - the JVM would have to lock on something for every write regardless of whether it will end up mattering or not just to adhere to a hypothetical 'no shearing can be observed' rule.
2. It is *also* obvious that the vast majority of 64-bit hardware out there is designed to fundamentally be incapable of shearing a `long`. CPUs update registers and memory positions atomically. You observe pre-update or post-update, you can't observe sheared values because the CPU just does not work that way.
3. Hence, trivially then, you can have a JMM clause (`long` values can be sheared) that is **literally impossible to trigger on most JVM implementations**.

Similar situations occur with `strictfp`. You will not be able to write code where you can observe that keyword making any difference for the vast, vast majority of arch+JVMimpl tuples.

I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't possible to write code that lets you observe a problem with letting constructors leak their `this` reference. The JMM merely reserves the right that some day, on some architecture, under some phase of the moon, if code can be executed faster but this requires foregoing any guarantee about syncing any writes a constructor did to other threads *if* that constructor leaked its ref, then a JVM implementor is free to do this. If that breaks your app, your app is bugged. It always was - it was just a bug that until that moment was not possible to trigger. You can file bugs with that JVM implementor all day, they'll close em as 'nope, you messed up because the JVM is working as designed'.

### Repercussions

The way the JMM section is written, where JVMS may or may not do a certain thing, means multicore field access is [*Here be dragons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons) territory. Ordinarily, you'd write some tests and these will ensure your code does what it wants. Ordinarily, if you're trying to figure out how stuff works, you write some experimental stuff and play around to learn.

**Neither plan works, at all, in multicore**. A JVM that says "I may or may not do X" *is nothing like a coin* - that doesn't mean that randomly it'll do it one run and do the other the next run. It tends to mean that it'll do the same thing every run today and tomorrow, but then next week it might do the other thing. Or even do one thing reliably on computer A and the other thing reliably on computer B. **Testing / playing around is overwhelmingly unlikely to find these differences**. A select few things really do let you observe both things more or less at 50%/50% chance but that's rare.

Given that it's untestable and you can't learn by playing, how is one to learn how to write proper, safe, reliable, bug-free multicore code? **Mostly you can't** - this is why you should think thrice before doing it.

Instead, use mechanisms that are much, much easier to test and understand. For example, instead of having 2 threads communicate with each other by way of field writes (which requires synchronization and is impossible to properly test), communicate with a database. transactions are much easier to understand. Or use a message queue perhaps.

Alternative to that, just.. eliminate all need for communications. Take, for example, a web server. It can trivially serve 50 connections simultaneously on 50 different threads and if these threads don't need to communicate with each other (and why would they need this? It's a webserver - unless that is powering some sort of chat platform, generally there's no need for that), then trivially there are no synchronization issues and these 'a JVM may or may not, dealer's choice' things are irrelevant to you.

The thing to remember is: **Any variable that is written to and accessed by more than one thread is a ticking time bomb**. Avoid like the plague. Whatever you can do not to have that - do that. The maintenance cost of writing code that needs to work like that is literally 10x to 100x higher because the only real way to 'test' it is to have someone extremely experienced at this go through it 'by hand' to ascertain it works properly. A simple test cannot do this, and you can't turn into an experienced hand simply by playing around with such code. You need to be able to quote chapter and verse of the JVMS to be capable of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Your program cannot provide any unexpected result because the execution of a thread is synchronised after the invocation of the `start` method on the corresponding `Thread` object. As a result, the write `this.state = 42` happens before the read in `System.out.println(state)` and the load will surely see the value of the store.

An example of a program that may exhibit such behaviour is:

```
class Example {
    static Example o = new Example();
    final int v;

    Example() {
        this.v = 42;
        Example.o = this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var reader = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                 System.out.println(Example.o.v);
            }
        });

        var writer = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                new Example();
            }
        });

        reader.start();
        writer.start();
        reader.join();
        writer.join();
    }
}
```

In this example, `this` is escaped to `Example.o` before the end of the constructor. As a result, there is no happen-before relationship between the read from `v` in `reader` and the write to `v` in `writer`, and the reader is allowed to observe a value of `0` from `o.v`. Note that the actual possibility of this phenomenon depends on how the methods are compiled, how the underlying architecture defines its memory model, etc. As a consequence, you may not be able to observe it at all. I think you may get a better chance with architectures with weaker memory model such as Arm or with flags that shuffles the instructions such as `-XX:+StressLCM`.

Comment: The phrase “the execution of a thread is synchronised” is misleading. The *happens-before* relationships are not the result of some synchronization, they are the primary mechanism in play. There’s a *happens-before* relationship between `state = 42;` and `t.start();` due to program order and there’s a *happens-before* relationship between `t.start();` and the started thread’s action(s), i.e. `System.out.println(state)`. Which establishes a *happens-before* relationship between `state = 42;` and `System.out.println(state)` due to transitivity.

Comment: @Holger The wording of the JLS in section 17.4.4. Synchronization order is: "An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.", which results in my usage of the word "synchronise" here.

Comment: It may sound similar but the term “synchronizes-with” clearly describes a relationship between two actions while “is synchronised” creates the impression of being in a special state. It’s important to emphasizes that the OP’s example has the predicted result due to a specific chain of actions while a different thread could see a different outcome (like with your example).